# Azure ruby sdk storage account create params, no method allow_blob_public_access

Tags: ruby, azure, azure-storage, azure-sdk-for-ruby

While doing a create on `storage_accounts`
I get:

`NoMethodError: undefined method allow_blob_public_access= for #Azure::Storage::Mgmt::V2019_06_01::Models::StorageAccountCreateParameter`

This is the [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/blob/master/management/azure_mgmt_storage/lib/2019-06-01/generated/azure_mgmt_storage/models/storage_account_create_parameters.rb#L83) to the `StorageAccountCreateParameter` on microsofts github.

My code looks like this:

```
sa_create_params = StorageModels::StorageAccountCreateParameters.new.tap do |sacp|
  sacp.kind = 'StorageV2'
  sacp.kind = payload['StorageAccountType'] if payload && payload['StorageAccountType']
  sacp.sku = sku
  sacp.location = params['region']
  sacp.access_tier = 'hot'
  sacp.access_tier = payload['AccessTier'] if payload && payload['AccessTier']
  sacp.tags = system_tags(params)
  sacp.allow_blob_public_access = false
end
```

Without the last line, regarding public access, it works just fine. I've tried upversioning the gems (hence the current version). And looking at their github it looks pretty self-explanatory. I'm at a loss, all help is much appreciated.

I'm using the following gems:
`ms_rest_azure 0.11.0`
`azure_mgmt_storage 0.21.0`

Update: it seems the name should be `sacp.properties.allow_blob_public_acces` as per [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/blob/3abbccf0561b4e8c9721d995e47a594120bff22b/management/azure_mgmt_storage/lib/2019-06-01/generated/azure_mgmt_storage/models/storage_account_create_parameters.rb#L235).
But this also throws a `NoMethodError`

Comment: Please provide API version you want to use. For example, use the code `Azure::Storage::Mgmt::V2019_06_01::Models::StorageAccountCreateParameters.new` to define oarams.

Comment: It does this in the framework somewhere. It is indeed `V2019_06_01`. It all works without the public_access line.

Comment: According to my test, if I use azure_mgmt_storage 0.22.0 and ms_rest_azure 0.12.0, it is ok for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated all azure gems to the latest version.
Relevant gems:

```
spec.add_dependency 'ms_rest_azure', '~> 0.12.0'
Spec.add_dependency 'azure_mgmt_storage', '~> 0.22.0'
```

This did the trick